# How can I find out if a wireless keyboard is encrypted / secure?

Tags: encryption, wireless, keyboard

I bought wireless keyboards from Ali Express (brand is Royal Kludge) that connect to the pc using either Bluetooth or a 2.4GHz USB dongle, and I want to make sure no one can read my keystrokes when I type my passwords for example.

Regardless of brand, how can I test it? Is there a way to sniff the communication and see? How can I find out the Bluetooth version?

Answer (score 1):

> Regardless of brand, how can I test it? Is there a way to sniff the communication and see?

This could be accomplished by an SDR capable of receiving 2.4Ghz.  This may not be cheap HackRF One for example is $300 at the time of this writing.  Then one would need to use SDR software to determine what protocol is being used and what data is going over that protocol.  Whether or not a protocol is encrypted can be a bit tough to determine.  And even worse, the quality of encryption is maybe impossible short of a degree in the subject.  But determining if there is some encryption may be as easy as pressing the same key over and over and see if the message sent is random or predictable.

> How can I find out the Bluetooth version?

If it is indeed Bluetooth, there are Bluetooth sniffing tools.  There are even some which integrate with common sniffing tools such as Wireshark.  These tools should be able to distinguish between Bluetooth versions.